# SSL Error: Unable to verify the first certificate for ingress kubernates service

Tags: node.js, ssl-certificate, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I am facing ssl certificate issue in ingress AKS
.yaml file is as below

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: #########
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - ##########
      secretName: ########
  rules:
    - host: ##########
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: #######
                port:
                  number: 8000
```

It is working on the web browser but in when try to access from postman or in node js code gives "SSL Error: Unable to verify the first certificate " error

Please help us!

Check the image attachment [image: click here]

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. @Prakash, have you got any update on this ?

Answer (score -4):

On postman go to settings => general
and disabel SSL certificate verification